# DOMException on accessing camera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getusermedia

I have without problem been able to accessing camera with javascript from chrome. But after last update of chrome (Version 74.0.3729.108 (Officiel version) (64-bit)) I get this DOMException

code: 0
message: "Permission denied"
name: "NotAllowedError"
**proto**: DOMException

My camera starts fine when I run on local or in e.g edge. Both local and from server

I am kind of stocked here so I really hope someone has some ideas!

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true
}).then(function (stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = function () {
        document.getElementById('splash').hidden = true;
        document.getElementById('app').hidden = false;
    };
}).catch(function (reason) {
    document.getElementById('errorMessage').textContent = 'No camera available.';
});
```

Comment: That is the standard message it has always shown when permission is denied, according to the docs. I would reset your site settings and Allow the camera again freshly. Maybe check your general camera/microphone settings in chrome. The feature works as expected for me (Win10 Chrome 74). Otherwise submit a but

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have reset chrome settings. And have no sites as blocked under settings camera. Could you explain further what you mean with "site settings". If there is some server side settings, CORS or something then I guess I would have same issue with e.g. edge or?

Comment: there is a specific setting per-site for MediaDevices. I think you can click the "lock" icon in the omnibox to see/reset those permissions